# Has Many Through relationship with accepts nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I understand that in order to use nested attributes I need to use a  has many through relationship instead of a has and belong to many so I have the following set up:

```
class Deed < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :deeds_title_abstracts
    has_many :title_abstracts, through: :deeds_title_abstracts
end

class TitleAbstract < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :deeds_title_abstracts
    has_many :deeds, through: :deeds_title_abstracts
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :deeds
end

class DeedsTitleAbstracts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deeds
  belongs_to :title_abstracts
end
```

In my Controller for Title Abstracts I have

```
def new
   @title_abstract = TitleAbstract.new(params[:title_abstract])
   @title_abstract.deeds.build
   respond_with(@title_abstract)
end
```

I am using cocoon in the view but I don't think that is the problem since I get this error:

```
  uninitialized constant TitleAbstract::DeedsTitleAbstract
```

I get the following when I look at it through the Console

```
   @title_abstract =TitleAbstract.new(params[:title_abstract])
   => #<TitleAbstract id: nil, name: nil, due_date: nil, comments: nil,     created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
   >> @title_abstract.deeds.build
   !! #<NameError: uninitialized constant TitleAbstract::DeedsTitleAbstract>
```

I think there is something wrong with my Has Many Through models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join model name is not per Rails Naming convention.  It should be called `DeedTitleAbstract` insted of `DeedsTitleAbstracts`.  So fixing this class name including the database table name is probably the best thing to do instead of incorporating a workaround(shown below).

The workaround for this is to supply the `class_name` option to `has_many :deeds_title_abstracts` as:

```
has_many :deeds_title_abstracts, class_name: 'DeedsTitleAbstract'
```

See: [Naming Conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions).

Also, your `belongs_to` relationship definitions need review.  `belongs_to` relationship should be defined on the model containing the foreign key and they should be singular not plural.

Here is an update to your relationship definition(i.e. of course after you've updated your join table migration including the model name change)

```
class Deed < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :deed_title_abstracts
    has_many :title_abstracts, through: :deed_title_abstracts
end

class TitleAbstract < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :deed_title_abstracts
    has_many :deeds, through: :deed_title_abstracts
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :deeds
end

class DeedTitleAbstract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deed
  belongs_to :title_abstract
end
```